# Should out-linking nodes be in rows or columns for calculating eigenvector centrality of a directed graph using igraph in R?

Tags: r, matrix, igraph

I've got a probabilistic adjacency matrix (probability that i knows j), and I want to calculate eigenvector centrality for all i.  The graph is directed.

Because the graph is directed, the adjacency matrix isn't symmetric.  Because the adjacency matrix isn't symmetric, the result depends on whether the matrix is transposed.  I suppose that one is the adjacency matrix for being linked to, and the other is the adjacency matrix for linking to others.  Which is which?

Here's a dummy example demonstrating the issue:

```
set.seed(333)
N=4
adj = matrix(runif(N^2),N)
diag(adj)<-0
A = graph.adjacency(adj,weighted=TRUE)
evcent(A,directed=TRUE)$vector

A = graph.adjacency(t(adj),weighted=TRUE)
evcent(A,directed=TRUE)$vector
```

Answer (score 3):

For directed graphs, matrix element `A[i,j]` represents the edge from vertex `i` to vertex `j`. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix